# Trying to press button of PopupWindow in thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, onclicklistener, popupwindow

I have a client that tries to connect to a server. After 5 seconds of there is timeout if the connection failed. I wonder to open a popup window with no connection sign and "Try again to connect" button. The popup is made in the thread, so if the connection failed the thread ends. Because of this, I put the on click method in my main activity. Why is not it working?

Code that thread runs after connection fails:

```
((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                        ((Activity) context).getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final PopupWindow noConnection = new PopupWindow(
                        inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_no_connection, null, false),
                        800,
                        800,
                        true);
                noConnection.setAnimationStyle(R.style.AnimationFade);
                noConnection.showAtLocation(((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.entrance_layout), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                globalClass.getErrorHandler().setNoConnectionWithServer(noConnection);
            }
        });
```

Code in main activity:

```
((GlobalClass) getApplicationContext()).initiateClass();
    globalClass = ((GlobalClass)getApplicationContext());

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupWindowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_no_connection, null, false);
    Button refreshConnection = (Button) popupWindowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_reconnect);
    refreshConnection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (globalClass.getErrorHandler().getNoConnectionWithServer() != null) {
                Communication communication = new Communication(globalClass, entrance.this);
                globalClass.setCommunication(communication);
                Thread t = new Thread(communication);
                t.start();
                globalClass.getErrorHandler().getNoConnectionWithServer().dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, the `onClick` callback is not called. Why? Because:

```
// you find button in a view 
View popupWindowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_no_connection, null, false); // this return new view
Button refreshConnection = (Button) popupWindowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_reconnect);

// but you create pop up with another view not from above (which contain listener)
final PopupWindow noConnection = new PopupWindow(
                    inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_no_connection, null, false),
                    800,
                    800,
                    true);
```

So how to solve it? there' are 2 ways:
 1. Save your pop up view after `inflate`ing  and re-use when creating pop-up view in your `runnable`.
 2. find your `Button` and `setOnclickListener` inside the `Runnable` after creating `pop-up view`

Answer (score 0):

I guess your animation is not allowing the button click. Try this without animation. I am having a same issue , my button which is animating from left to right is not click able during and after animation. And its working without animation.